# SSSD - Unable to Authenticate Against Google LDAP After 20.04 Upgrade - Could not start TLS encryption. unknown error

Tags: authentication, google, ldap, tls, sssd

I'm trying to authenticate against Google LDAP (G Suite/Google Admin) to allow my clients to log in using their Google credentials.  I have no visibility on the LDAP side of things I can only generate the cert/key combo in Google Admin.

This was working well for me on 18.04, but with the upgrade to 20.04 I cannot get it to work.  Additionally, it *does* work for me in other distributions (Fedora) I've included some details below.  I read a Canonical post about TLS 1.X and below being disabled with 20.04; does that mean this could be a cipher suite issue?

**Error Message**

[systemctl status sssd](https://pastebin.com/qAN8jLFy)

● sssd.service - System Security Services Daemon
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/sssd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-08-02 15:38:22 EDT; 6s ago
Main PID: 3165 (sssd)
Tasks: 4 (limit: 9043)
Memory: 37.3M
CGroup: /system.slice/sssd.service
├─3165 /usr/sbin/sssd -i --logger=files
├─3167 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_be --domain mydomain.com --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files
├─3168 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_nss --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files
└─3169 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_pam --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files

Aug 02 15:38:21 JY2D353 systemd[1]: Starting System Security Services Daemon...

Aug 02 15:38:21 JY2D353 sssd[3165]: Starting up

Aug 02 15:38:22 JY2D353 sssd_be[3167]: Starting up

Aug 02 15:38:22 JY2D353 sssd_pam[3169]: Starting up

Aug 02 15:38:22 JY2D353 sssd_nss[3168]: Starting up

***Aug 02 15:38:22 JY2D353 sssd_be[3167]: Could not start TLS encryption. unknown error***

Aug 02 15:38:22 JY2D353 systemd[1]: Started System Security Services Daemon.

**Last Working Config**

- Ubuntu 18.04
- SSSD 1.16.0
- Followed instructions located [here](https://helpcenter.itopia.com/en/articles/2394004-configuring-google-cloud-identity-ldap-on-ubuntu-16-04-for-user-logins)

I am still able to successfully authenticate using this setup.

**Current Configuration**

- Ubuntu 20.04
- SSSD 2.4.0
- Same configuration

**Logs/conf**

[etc/sssd.conf](https://pastebin.com/qmUP6qsE)

[sssd_mydomain.com.log](https://pastebin.com/xGrpV2Fe)

[sssd.log](https://pastebin.com/fzjwqh1m)

[sssd_pam.log](https://pastebin.com/2utzuPPw)

[sssd_nss.log](https://pastebin.com/NHMZwpq2)

[openssl s_client](https://pastebin.com/DH5S2vtD)

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with TLS 1.3 and google requiring SNI, which apparently isn't properly supported in Ubuntu 20.  A workaround which seems to be working for me is to add to the domain section of `sssd.conf`:

```
ldap_tls_cipher_suite = NORMAL:!VERS-TLS1.3
```

which forces TLS1.2 and removes the SNI issue.